# Asynchronous WCF Query Final step

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, asynchronous-wcf-call

I am trying to learn how to implement an asynchronous pattern to query multiple wcf services concurrently, but do not know how to check that all concurrent calls are complete. I have a class that executes the asynchronous operations and then adds to a List as operations complete:

```
   public static class ODataAsync
    {
        static DataServiceContext ServiceContext;
        static List<DynamicEntity> Results = new List<DynamicEntity>(); 

        private static void GetAsync(string serviceUri, NameValueCollection queryOptions, IAuthenticationScheme authenticationScheme)
        {
            string baseUri;
            string entitySet;
            string entityKey;
            string queryString;
            ValidateServiceUri(serviceUri, out baseUri, out entitySet, out entityKey, out queryString);
            string resource = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(entityKey) ? entitySet + "(" + entityKey + ")" : entitySet;

            DataServiceContext context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri(baseUri));
            context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;

            ServiceContext = context; 

            DataServiceContextHandler handler = new DataServiceContextHandler(authenticationScheme);
            handler.HandleGet(context);

            DataServiceQuery<EntryProxyObject> query = context.CreateQuery<EntryProxyObject>(resource);

            NameValueCollection options = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
            options.Add(queryOptions);

            foreach (string key in options.AllKeys)
            {
                query = query.AddQueryOption(key, options[key]);
            }

            try
            {
                query.BeginExecute(GetAsyncComplete, query);
            }
            catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("An error occurred during query execution.", ex); 
            }
        }

        private static void GetAsyncComplete(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            QueryOperationResponse<EntryProxyObject> response = 
                ((DataServiceQuery<EntryProxyObject>)result).EndExecute(result) as QueryOperationResponse<EntryProxyObject>; 

            IList<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>(); 

            foreach (EntryProxyObject proxy in response)
            {
                DynamicEntity entity = new DynamicEntity(proxy.Properties);
                Results.Add(entity);
            }

            while (response.GetContinuation() != null)
            {
                Uri uri = response.GetContinuation().NextLinkUri;

                response = ServiceContext.Execute<EntryProxyObject>(uri) as QueryOperationResponse<EntryProxyObject>;

                foreach (EntryProxyObject proxy in response)
                {
                    DynamicEntity entity = new DynamicEntity(proxy.Properties);
                    Results.Add(entity);
                }
            }
        }    
    }
```

My 2 questions are:

1) How do I ensure that I only get the List Result(s) when all concurrent calls are finished? For instance if call GetAsync() within a loop, starting several concurrent processes, I need to ensure that they are all finished before taking the data out of the List Result.

2) Can I use BeginExecute() inside the GetContinuation() call and recursively use the same method GetAsyncComplete() as the callback function ? Or would that create a ton of threads and actually slow things down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the static [WaitHandle.WaitAll(WaitHandle[] waitHandles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6w25xa6.aspx) method. There's a great code example on that page.

Typically, any class implementing the asynchronous pattern will define methods of the form:

```
IAsyncResult BeginXXX(AsyncCallback callback, Object state);

Result EndXXX(IAsyncResult asyncResult);
```

Calling `BeginXXX` invokes the method asynchronously, and calling `EndXXX` forces the current thread to wait until the asynchronous method completes.

To make multiple asynchronous calls, all you need to do is call `BeginXXX` as many times as necessary, and then call `WaitHandle.WaitAll(...)` passing in the IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle for all of the calls that you want to wait for.

To answer your second question, yes you can use `GetAsynComplete` recursively. The `state` parameter given to `BeginXXX` call is used to identify the request, and can be accessed via the `IAsyncResult.UserState` property - so you can match a request to a response.

Whether or not this is a good thing is a bit more subjective. Usually, async calls go via a threadpool, so creating lots of them at once can exhaust the available threads and after that, new calls get queued until a thread becomes available. There is some overhead in switching between threads, but that is probably not going to be significant (unless you have a very large number of threads), compared to the time taken to do it synchronously.